java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /project/helloworld-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
I am trying to package an application with maven as a native executable and getting the following error:
Error: Invalid Path entry helloworld-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /project/helloworld-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar

For more context, I am working in IntelliJ and ran the following commands:
quarkus create app com.example:helloworld --extension=resteasy

then cd to the helloworld folder
ran the app with ./mvnw quarkus:dev, everything looked good except for some reason the helloworld-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar was placed in a folder called helloworld-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-native-image-source-jar within the target directory rather than directly into target.
Created a Dockerfile in my target directory with the following:
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal:8.4
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work && chmod "g+rwX" /work && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application
EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001
CMD ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]

updated .dockerignore to have the following:
# Ignore everything
*

# Allow these files and directories
!pom.xml
!mvnw
!mvnw.cmd
!src/
!target/*-runner
!target/*-runner.jar
!target/lib/*
!target/quarkus-app/*

and finally ran ./mvnw package -Pnative "-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true" which threw the error after the docker run line.
More specifically in the logs I see an error that says [error]: Build step io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.NativeImageBuildStep$ImageGenerationFailureException: Image generation failed. Exit code: 20
Other info: I have the most recent version of GraalVM installed. JAVA_HOME is Java 17. PATH variables include %JAVA_HOME%\bin and a separate variable to the GraalVM path.

Do you have reproducer, e.g. in form of a git repository?

For conext: If i follow the steps provided (quarkus create app com.example:helloworld --extension=resteasy && cd helloworld && ./mvnw package -Pnative "-Dquarkus.native.container-build=true"), the application builds just fine.

I don't have a reproducer but I can create one. Do you know of any other configuration steps I may have missed? GraalVM setup etc?

Since the native build takes place in a container, a local graalvm-/mandrel-setup is not necessary. It might be possible that the docker setup is the culprit, i.e. that the copy of the *.jar to the buiilder image fails.

Yeah that makes sense. I didn't do much in terms of docker setup. I have version 25.0.4-rd but that's all I really did there.

It seems that ./mvnw package builds successfully. But when I add the flags it does not. Also I'm using windows powershell.
